# print() to console log with color

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, logging, ansi-colors

The code is:

```
let redColor = "\u{001B}[0;31m"
var message = "Some Message"
print(redColor + message)  //This doesn't work
print("\(redColor)\(message)") //This also doesn't work
```

and the output would look like this:

```
[0;31mSome Message
```

I've also read this post: [Color ouput with Swift command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807925/color-ouput-with-swift-command-line-tool), and it doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to use libraries.

Comment: As [mentioned in the linked-to Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807925/color-ouput-with-swift-command-line-tool#comment50249685_27808423), setting the color  works when the program is run in a Terminal window, but *not* in the Xcode console.

Comment: oh god. Seriously?. I guess I'll just use emoji's to mark my logs then.

Comment: Also confirmed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005769/any-way-to-print-in-color-with-nslog: *"... as Xcode debugging console doesn't seem to support coloring."*

Comment: ok thanks man. should I keep this question open or should I close it?

Comment: Xcode's terminal window does not support coloring. Its `$TERM` value is nil. There's no way to have colors in the Xcode's debugger area. *But* you can attach another terminal as output (in Xcode's prefs) and there, the output will support colors.

Comment: @ZonilyJame If you choose to close it, don't forget to validate my answer please.

Comment: @DanylS I won't close it but I'll place you as the answer, we never know if there might be a change for the next iterations of Xcode

Comment: Ok, alright @ZonilyJame.

Comment: Why don't give it a try: https://github.com/zhihuitang/SwiftMagic

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Nowadays, Xcode debugging console doesn't support coloring.

Comment: is there any other option available ?

Comment: This project might give you some hope:  [**XcodeColors**](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors)

Comment: An alternative to color your logs **[is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548072/5623035)**

Answer (score 62):

Xcode doesn't support console coloring since Xcode 8.

But Since Xcode is fully unicode compatible, you can use **emojis** instead! for example you can use You can use `⚠️` for warning messages and  for error messages. (like the Xcode itself)

Or simply use these note books as a color:

```
: error message
: warning message
: ok status message
: action message
: canceled status message
: Or anything you like and want to recognize immediately by color
```

for example:

```
print("⚠️", "Touch is not disabled as expected")
```

---

## Bones

Using this method will help you to find the logs in the source code as fast as ⚡️ by a simple eye scan:

[image: Demo]

And you can search for them  to let the Xcode take you there. Take a look at this result comparison:

#### Custom emoji search

[image: emoji search]

vs

#### Word search

[image: word search]

Comment: Soooo creative! Never thought about it! hahaha thanks!

Comment: works like a charm, even for the build machine on the pipeline! 

Answer (score 7):

Adding to [@Mojtaba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548072/5623035), you can use this for automating logging:

```
enum LogType: String{
case error
case warning
case success
case action
case canceled
}


class Logger{

 static func log(_ logType:LogType,_ message:String){
        switch logType {
        case LogType.error:
            print("\n Error: \(message)\n")
        case LogType.warning:
            print("\n Warning: \(message)\n")
        case LogType.success:
            print("\n Success: \(message)\n")
        case LogType.action:
            print("\n Action: \(message)\n")
        case LogType.canceled:
            print("\n Cancelled: \(message)\n")
        }
    }

}
```

You can use it this way:

```
Logger.log(.error, "Invalid Credit Information")
```

Comment: You are using special Unicode characters. It would be preferable to provide these as escape sequences to avoid Unicode in the code.

Comment: Great answer and great solution!

Answer (score 2):

As @LeslieGodwin mentioned, the [XcodeColors](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors) Xcode plugin adds color support to the Xcode console **(for Xcode versions below 8)**

Answer (score 2):

Adding my own contribution:

```
struct Logger {
    /// Type of logs available
    enum LogType: String {
        /// To log a message
        case debug
        /// To log a warning
        case warning
        /// To log an error
        case error
    }
    
    /// Logs a debug message
    /// - Parameter message: Message to log
    /// - Parameter file: File that calls the function
    /// - Parameter line: Line of code from the file where the function is call
    /// - Parameter function: Function that calls the functon
    /// - Returns: The optional message that was logged
    @discardableResult
    static func d(message: String, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) -> String{
        return log(type: .debug, message: message, file: file, line: line, function: function)
    }
    
    /// Logs a warning message
    /// - Parameter message: Message to log
    /// - Parameter file: File that calls the function
    /// - Parameter line: Line of code from the file where the function is call
    /// - Parameter function: Function that calls the functon
    /// - Returns: The optional message that was logged
    @discardableResult
    static func w(message: String, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) -> String{
        return log(type: .warning, message: message, file: file, line: line, function: function)
    }
    
    /// Logs an error message
    /// - Parameter message: Message to log
    /// - Parameter file: File that calls the function
    /// - Parameter line: Line of code from the file where the function is call
    /// - Parameter function: Function that calls the functon
    /// - Returns: The optional message that was logged
    @discardableResult
    static func e(message: String, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) -> String{
        return log(type: .error, message: message, file: file, line: line, function: function)
    }
    
    /// Logs an message
    /// - Parameter logType: Type of message to log
    /// - Parameter message: Message to log
    /// - Parameter file: File that calls the function
    /// - Parameter line: Line of code from the file where the function is call
    /// - Parameter function: Function that calls the functon
    /// - Returns: The optional message that was logged
    @discardableResult
    static func log(type logType: LogType = .debug, message: String, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line, function: String = #function) -> String{
        var logMessage = ""
        
        switch logType{
        case .debug:
            logMessage += ""
        case .warning:
            logMessage += ""
        case .error:
            logMessage += ""
        }
        
        let fileName = file.components(separatedBy: "/").last ?? ""
        logMessage += " \(fileName) -> LINE: \(line) -> \(function) => \(message)"
        
        print(logMessage)
        return logMessage
    }

}
```

You can always change the icons using "crtl+cmd+space"

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a replacement color logging within Xcode see this new swift-log feature that I created.

https://github.com/nneuberger1/swift-log-console-colors

It uses the new standard swift-log compatible library.

The output will look like this if passing in .cool

```
2021-05-09T16:13:30-0500  debug thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:13:30-0500 ℹ️ info thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:13:30-0500  notice thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:13:30-0500 ⚠️ warning thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:13:30-0500 ⚡ critical thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:13:30-0500  error thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
```

The output will look like this if passing in .rainbow

```
2021-05-09T16:17:07-0500  debug thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:17:07-0500  info thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:17:07-0500  notice thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:17:07-0500  warning thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:17:07-0500  critical thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
2021-05-09T16:17:07-0500  error thingsAboveAdmin : Testing log levels..
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking Mojtaba Hosseini's answer, I have incorporated it into a Log class to have very detailed logging:

The class is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import OSLog


class Log {
    #if DEBUG
    static let logLevel = "deiwv"
    #else
    static let logLevel = "e"
    #endif
    static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? ""
    static var flags = [  "e" : "",
                        "w" : "",
                        "i" : "",
                        "d" : "",
                        "v" : ""
                  ]
    
    static func setup(_ fileStr: String, _ funcStr: String, _ line: Int, _ level: String) -> String {
        var fileName = fileStr.components(separatedBy: "/").last ?? ""
        fileName = fileName.components(separatedBy:".").first ?? ""
        fileName = fileName.padding(toLength: 20, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
        let funcString = funcStr.padding(toLength: 10, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
        let lineNum = "\(line)".padding(toLength: 4, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
        let flag = flags[level] ?? ""
        return "\(flag)\(level.uppercased()) \(fileName):\(funcString):\(lineNum)"
    }
    
    static func i(_ msg: String, fileStr: String = #file, funcStr: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
        if(logLevel.contains("i")) {
            Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: setup(fileStr, funcStr, line, "i")).info("\(msg)")
        }
    }
    static func e(_ msg: String, fileStr: String = #file, funcStr: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
        if(logLevel.contains("e")) {
            Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: setup(fileStr, funcStr, line, "e")).error("\(msg)")
        }
    }
    static func d(_ msg: String, fileStr: String = #file, funcStr: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
        if(logLevel.contains("d")) {
            Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: setup(fileStr, funcStr, line, "d")).debug("\(msg)")
        }
    }
    static func w(_ msg: String, fileStr: String = #file, funcStr: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
        if(logLevel.contains("w")) {
            Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: setup(fileStr, funcStr, line, "w")).warning("\(msg)")
        }
    }
    static func v(_ msg: String, fileStr: String = #file, funcStr: String = #function, line: Int = #line) {
        if(logLevel.contains("v")) {
            Logger(subsystem: subsystem, category: setup(fileStr, funcStr, line, "v")).log("\(msg)")
        }
    }
}
```

This allows logging i.e. as follows:

```
Log.i("This is the logged comment")
```

or

```
Log.e("This is an error")
```

Output is tagged and shows the filename, the function name and the line number where the logging occurs, making it much easier to find something in a larger project:

```
2023-04-12 19:03:22.006185+0100 OOHSystem[34170:6047034] [I InitialViewControlle:viewDidLoa:27  ] Loaded
2023-04-12 19:03:22.006766+0100 OOHSystem[34170:6047034] [I InitialViewControlle:viewWillAp:33  ] Started
2023-04-12 19:03:22.007867+0100 OOHSystem[34170:6047034] [I InitialViewControlle:viewWillAp:47  ] Called from startup
2023-04-12 19:03:22.078324+0100 OOHSystem[34170:6047034] [I UIDeviceExtensions  :UIDevice  :110 ] identfied: arm64
2023-04-12 19:03:22.079177+0100 OOHSystem[34170:6047034] [V Globals             :token     :17  ] 3ae51797ac5a8619010352's
```

By default, production only logs errors but of course that is easy to configure.

There may be better or more elegant ways of achieving this, but it works for me.

Comment: This is begging to use an enum instead of strings for the levels.