# Xcode console, unicode with NSLog in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unicode

I'm trying to print colored text in the console in Xcode with XcodeColors (works on Xcode 8 when [unsigned](https://github.com/nrbrook/MakeXcodePluginsWork)) using NSLog.

This doesn't work:

`NSLog("\u{001b}[fg255,0,0;Test\u{001b}[;")`

I get `\^[[fg255,0,0;Test\^[[;` in the console.

However, these do work:

`print("\u{001b}[fg255,0,0;Test\u{001b}[;")
NSLog("\u{001b}[fg255,0,0;Test\u{001b}[;")`

i.e. using print or adding a unicode symbol to the string causes it to work. How can I get this working without doing either of those?

Comment: What's wrong with `print`?

Comment: I want the date/app name so it matches the indent of other logs. I'm sure I could achieve this other ways but I thought there must be a simple solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to print in color with NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005769/any-way-to-print-in-color-with-nslog)