# Xcode: How to print colored PRINT statement in console output?

Tags: swift, xcode, printing, textcolor

I am new to Swift and I was wondering if it is possible to print colored print statement in the console of Xcode..

Here's an example:

```
print("Hi my name is John Doe")
```

now I want to print this statement in red color, how would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to print in color with NSLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005769/any-way-to-print-in-color-with-nslog)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That feature has been killed by Apple from Xcode 8. 
But you can use [SwiftyBeaver](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/SwiftyBeaver) to achieve it.

```
let log = SwiftyBeaver.self
let console = ConsoleDestination()
log.addDestination(console)

// default xcode colors
console.levelColor.verbose = " "
```